# How to write Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object on asp.net output stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, excel-2007, excel-interop

I was using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in C# to create a custom `.xlsx` file.

In doing so I created a [`Workbook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook.aspx) object.  Due to the nature of complex SQL queries to grab the data, process it, and apply via Interop the custom styles and formatting the code is very lengthy.  Not to mention the very careful process of avoiding memory leaks from the Interop itself, and ensuring that Excel actually closes properly after running.

I originally was testing it out as a console application, and got it working to my satisfaction.  What it does is save the end result to the filesystem using the [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook_members.aspx) member.

However, my next goal was to instead redirect the output as an output stream to `asp.net` similar to this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519026/how-do-you-stream-an-excel-2007-or-word-2007-file-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp).  I've done some rudimentary research and I cannot seem to find an approach that does not involve first saving the Workbook to the server's file system.  This may cause conflicts if several users are accessing at the same time, etc.

So my question is, is there an easy way to set the asp.net `ContentType` for `.xlsx` and stream out the `Workbook` object without saving it to the file system?  If not, is there a way `asp.net` can save temporary files automatically without conflicts, serve the temp file, and then delete the temp file after it's been served?

Comment: using excel interop on server is not supported (please google it), my best advice is dont do that, use free excel libraries like EPPlus

Comment: Excel doesn't work reliably in a multi-user environment (like your web application). This is documented somewhere on Microsoft's web site. You better start looking for a different approach for generating Excel files. There are many good third-party libraries available.

Comment: OK, cool.  Going to adapt to EPPlus then.  I didn't realize interop wasn't well supported for asp.net.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that you should avoid using Excel Interop server-side, and the third party libraries I've used (EPPlus, Aspose) all support streaming the output.  However, if you want to save temporary files without conflict you can use [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx).

If your ASP.NET app is running under an account without a profile, you may need to give it write access to `%WINDIR%\Temp` or whatever temporary directory it uses.

Comment: I didn't try this answer, I ended up going with EPPlus.  Accepting to close it, though.